# Removing a comma from a comma-parenthesized subclause

Tags: commas

I have written the following:

> The credentials, checked by the gatekeeper, take the form of...

But my wife says that "it would read better without the first comma". Is what she suggests allowed by the rules of grammar?

Comment: Either 2 commas, or none. It's a matter of style but nothing grammatically wrong either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one comma is not good.

However, removing both commas change the  "reduced object relative passive clause" from a non-defining one to a defining one (ie

> 'The credentials checked by the gatekeeper take the form of...'

=

> 'Those credentials which are/were checked by the gatekeeper take the
>   form of...').